# Can you have a Facebook group with a trademark company's name?

Tags: united-states, trademark

Can you force a Facebook group to change their name if it matches your trademark?  One group I am in is thinking about changing their name because of this and it is a group of current and former members of that organization. This is within the U.S. and the organization is events and adventures.

Comment: Impossible to say without more detail, it depends on the usage. The use of a trademarked word may or may not be trademark infringement depending on the context. Calling an Arizona-based social group "Arizona", for example, would likely not infringe upon the iced tea maker's trademark, but calling a beverage-selling group "Coca-Cola" might well be be infringement.

Answer (score 2):

Trademarks are all about customer confusion.   The ruling factor is: is a reasonable person likely to confuse the thing with the trademark holder's thing?

However, you're allowed to be *referential* - for instance say you have a group for former Microsoft employees.  You aren't prohibited from using the term Microsoft. You have a practical reason since it defines what your group is.    Calling themselves "Angry Microsoft Expats" isn't likely to be confused with official Microsoft (even if Microsoft may not be amused), but calling themselves "Microsoft Exit" - *see, that kind of sounds like a product*.

But here's the thing. A lot of people get confused by free speech.  If the site **stores** content (words, sounds, images, video, haptics)  *free speech does not exist*. What exists is **freedom of the press**, which is enjoyed by **them who own a press**.  It's like that.  You have no rights. Facebook can put up or delete anything they please, for any reason or no reason at all (e.g. sales rep says "customer will do an ad buy if we delete it").*

If you don't like that, you can get your own press for $17.99 at GoDaddy.

* Except for a very narrow list of reasons such as "you are black", but even this has constraints.